# Is there a way to downcast a generic class to an instance with a derived T?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Let's say I have the following class I use to wrap some items of a given type:

```
public class IndexedModelWithValue<T>
{
    public IndexedModelWithValue(T value, int index)
    {
        Index = index;
        InnerValue = value;
    } 

    public int index;

    public T InnerValue { get; }
}
```

And I have these two classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
```

At some point, I load different objects (here we'll just use the `Dog` class) that all inherit from the same base type, so I'll have something like this:

```
Dog dog = LoadMyDerivedAnimalFromSomewhere();
Animal animal = dog;

// In my actual code I have something like
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = LoadMyDerivedAnimalsFromSomewhere();
```

And then proceed to wrap all those items so that I end up with something like:

```
IndexedModelWithValue<Animal> indexedAnimal = new IndexedModelWithValue(animal, 0);
```

Now, I know that animal in the indexed model is in fact a `Dog` instance, so is there a way to end up with a `IndexedModelWithValue<Dog>` object from that one?

I thought about using an interface (I wouldn't mind ending up with something like `IIndexedModelWithValue<Dog>` as long as I get the `Dog` type in there), but from what I understand, a covariant class can only be cast in the opposite direction (`IEnumerable<String>` to `IEnumerable<object` and not vice-versa), and I can't use a contravariant class here as the class exposes a T parameter.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**: for clarification, here's how I'm ending up with my list:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = LoadAllMyAnimalsFromSomewhere();
IEnumerable<IndexedModelWithValue<Animal>> = animals.Select((item, i) => new IndexedModelWithValue(item, i));
```

---

**Temporary (bad) workaround**: Right now the solution I'm using is to add a method to the indexed class:

```
public IndexedModelWithValue<TValue> Downcast<TValue>() where TValue : T
{
    return new IndexedModelWithValue<TValue>((TValue)InnerValue, Index);
}
```

So that I can just do:

```
IndexedModelWithValue<Dog> indexedDog = indexedAnimal.Downcast<Dog>();
```

The only issue is that this way *I'm creating a new instance of the `IndexedModelWithValue` class every time I call this method* (so I'm wasting memory and CPU time) when in fact I just want to cast that object to my derived type.

---

**Solution**: here's the method I'm using right now to solve the issue:

```
public static IEnumerable<ICovariantIndexedModelWithValue<T>> New([NotNull] IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IndexedModelWithValue<>).MakeGenericType(item.GetType()), item, index);
        yield return (ICovariantIndexedModelWithValue<T>)instance;
        index++;
    }
}
```

I can just call this and pass the original list to get a covariant wrapped list where each individual item has the "right type" depending on its derived type.

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface ICovariantIndexedModelWithValue<out T>
{
    int Index { get; }

    T InnerValue { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects themselves are created strongly typed (e.g. when an `IndexedModelWithValue` is made for a `Dog`, it is made as a `IndexedModelWithValue<Dog>` and not as a `IndexedModelWithValue<Animal>` ), an interface could be used to support the (co)variance and all the different values stored in a list of the interface type.

*edit* Based on the source being of type `Animal`: Although not a very nice solution as far as build time checks goes, the strongly typed `IndexedModelWithValue` could be created with `Activator.CreateInstance` and `typeof(IndexedModelWithValue<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType())` (where a is the `Animal` variable).
(If the method that loads the data could somehow create other objects, better design time functionality could be added)

Based on your current example, the enumerable can be created with:
`LoadAllMyAnimalsFromSomewhere().Select((a,i)=> (IIndexedModelWithValue<Animal>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IndexedModelWithValue<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType()), a,i));`

Linqpad safe code:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = LoadData().Select((a,i)=> (IIndexedModelWithValue<Animal>) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IndexedModelWithValue<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType()), a,i)).ToList();

    foreach(var t in list.OfType<IIndexedModelWithValue<Dog>>())
        Console.WriteLine(t);
}

static IEnumerable<Animal> LoadData()
{
    yield return new Dog();
    yield return new Gecko();
}

public class IndexedModelWithValue<T>:IIndexedModelWithValue<T>
{
    public IndexedModelWithValue(T value, int index)
    {
        Index = index;
        InnerValue = value;
    } 

    public int Index{get;set;}

    public T InnerValue { get; }
}

public interface IIndexedModelWithValue<out T>
{
    int Index{get;}
    T InnerValue {get;}
}

class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
class Gecko:Animal{}
```

Comment: I've thought about this, the issue is that when I'm creating the list of `IndexedModelWithValue` objects I only have the base `IEnumerable<Animal>` list returned by the method that loads all the data, so I wouldn't know how to create strongly typed `IndexedModelWithValue` objects from there :/

Comment: Added an option for that. Although not the most design time friendly solution, creating the type dynamically with `MakeGenericType` should be safe enough as long as you know the input (and constructor). Small sidenote, if large lists are concerned it might be better to keep a dictionary with the type constructors instead of using `MakeGenericType` each type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `indexedDog` and `indexedAnimal` are two different types. Its not just that you are storing them in a different shaped box, the actual types are different. So there is no way you can do this without creating a new object as you are. If you want to avoid wasting memory, cpu or anything else then you'll need to create the object as an `IndexedModelWithValue<Dog>` in the first place. If you know that its definitely a dog though then this is what you should be doing. If you have a definite dog then don't create an `IndexedModelWithValue<Animal>` in the first place and your problem will be gone. Without seeing the code where you are creating the objects its hard to say exactly how to do this but generics should allow you to create the type you want.

Comment: The problem is that I have different nested types that are returned by a method as a single list of the base type, and I use that list to create the indexed instances. 
I could use a variant interface for the indexed class and assign derived types to it (so that each element would have the "right" type), but I still wouldn't know how to generate derived `IndexedModelWithValue` instances from a single `IEnumerable<Animal>` list.

Comment: How is it that at some point you magically know that you definitely have a dog then? And do you really need `IndexedModelWithValue<Dog>` rather than `IndexedModelWithValue<Animal>`? And if you really must convert from one type to the other is it really causing you performance issues such that you need to worry about this?

Comment: I know that because I'm using a `DataTemplateSelector` to check the actual type of the inner value of the model and to pick the right `DataTemplate`. The cast is used in each different template to strongly-type the `DataContext` property, as I need it to be able to use compiled bindings (it's a UWP app).